# error:cannotfindymbolsettings.setAppCachePath(options.appCachePath);symbol:methodsetAppCachePath(String)location: variablesettings of type WebSettings

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

There is a flutter in-appwebview issue if any one know the solution please help

> `C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:280:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCachePath(options.appCachePath);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:494:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:504:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:515:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCachePath(ctx.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:517:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:521:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_inappwebview-5.4.3+7\android\src\main\java\com\pichillilorenzo\flutter_inappwebview\in_app_webview\InAppWebView.java:767:
> error: cannot find symbol
> settings.setAppCachePath(newOptions.appCachePath);
> ^   symbol:   method setAppCachePath(String)   location: variable settings of type WebSettings Note: Some input files use or
> override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
> details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 7 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 11s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 `

Answer (score 3):

Such Methods are remove, you can see [Android Developer Document](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/33/changes/android.webkit.WebSettings)

Now Only LOAD_DEFAULT is enough set this code

```
viewer.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [webview_flutter_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus) package. It's simple and easy to implement. I provide an example code for you.

First of all, you need to install the package:
`flutter pub add webview_flutter_plus`

Then you need to import it:
`import 'package:webview_flutter_plus/webview_flutter_plus.dart';`

And there is the example code that you can modify:

```dart
WebViewPlus(
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    controller.loadUrl('https://example.com'); // the URL that you want to load
  },
),
```

And if you build to android you need to set `minSdkVersion` to `19`

Then you need to add these lines to your android manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If you use HTTP domains you need to add this line to your `application` section in in your manifest file like this:

```xml
<application
       ...
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
       ...
</application>
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Update `flutter_inappwebview` version to latest.
It works for me.

```
flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+2
```